# Unable to Iterate through Excel.Shapes in .NET Core 3.1 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, com

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Object Lib 16 inside WPF .NET3.1
this error is shown when I try to iterate Excel shapes.

```
                xl.Shapes allShapes = wSheet.Shapes;
                foreach(xl.Shape shape in allShapes)
```

`Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumerator' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.":"System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumerator`

I use same .NET and COM Excel lib in Winform Project Everything works fine.
why only WPF is this isse?

Comment: Core has broken many things with COM support with .NET. You should try with more recent versions of .NET core (like 6) https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-december-13-2022/

Comment: I tried with.NET 5.0 with the same code at first, and it was not working. But after creating a clean project with.NET 5.0, it is working fine now without error.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the VSTO libraries only work with classic .NET Framework. In .NET Core (and .NET >=5) they will not work properly. The problem is definitely not related to WPF.